# DOM Parser in Java, with attributes and tag values

Tags: java, parsing, dom

```
    <Document>
    <Folder>
        <Placemark id="kml_1">
            <name>$1.00 / hr 2hr time limit</name>
            <snippet> </snippet>
            <styleUrl>#ParkingMeterStyler_KMLStyler</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <SchemaData schemaUrl="#Meter_Rates_and_Time_Limits">
                    <SimpleData name="RATE">$1.00</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="LIMIT">2hr</SimpleData>
                </SchemaData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <LineString>
                <coordinates>-123.100739208611,49.2630169018194,0 -123.100348847572,49.2630078055425,0 </coordinates>
            </LineString>
        </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document>
```

I'm having trouble extracting the "$1.00" and the "2hr" in:

```
<SimpleData name="RATE">$1.00</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="LIMIT">2hr</SimpleData>
```

So far, my code looks like this and extracts the "name" and "coordinates" successfully:

```
public class Debuger {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

      try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("parkingMeter.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Placemark");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

           Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
           if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

              Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

              System.out.println("Name : " + getTagValue("name", eElement));

              if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equals("RATE")){
                  System.out.println("Rate : " + getTagValue("SimpleData", eElement));
              }else if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equals("LIMIT")) {
                   System.out.println("Limit : " + getTagValue("SimpleData", eElement));
                }

              System.out.println("Coordinates : " + getTagValue("coordinates", eElement));

           }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();
  }

}
```

I'm really stuck here, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about using XPath for this?

Comment: Not really, I had never heard of XPath before.

Comment: It is useful when you want to extract specific information out of an XML file. It is not useful for converting a complete XML file into Java objects, a process known as marshalling the data, for that I usually use JAXB, but if all you need to do is extract some particular bits of info, consider looking into using XPath.

Comment: I'm reading right now about it, but in the end I do need to use the data to create java objects so maybe JAXB would be better. I would need to read on JAXB as well though :P, thank you!

Comment: Well, yes, if you need to convert all of the XML data to a similar structure in Java classes, then JAXB is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

Your `<ExtendedData>` tag is 4th child node of `<Placemark>` node and you are only traversing  tag children e.g.  node and through `getTagValue`, you are getting first grand child.

```
   NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
```

Please correct the traversal by iterating child nodes of  node. It should work.

Comment: Oooh, yeah you're right, that makes sense. Should be an easy fix then, thank you :).

Comment: Humm, I can't seem, to fix it...Wanna give me any more hints please?

Comment: This prints `nList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(7).getChildNodes().item(1).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent()` the `$1.00` and this `nList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(7).getChildNodes().item(1).getChildNodes().item(3).getTextContent()` prints the `2hr`. Here `nList` is used after this line `NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Placemark");`. Fix the traversal accordingly. It should be all good.

Comment: In the I changed the whole thing, but I forgot about getTextContent() which you just posted, this solved my issue, thank you so much! :)